# AngularJS - fetch single post

Tags: javascript, get, angularjs, parameters

I have a list of data and a single page where I want to display a single post.

**Service:**

```
app.factory('dealerService', function($resource) {
   return $resource('files/js/dealer.json', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params:{id:'@id'}, isArray:true}
  });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('DealerDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, dealerService) {
    $scope.dealer = dealerService.get({id: $routeParams.id});
});
```

**Route:**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/dealer/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html', controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

**Template:**

```
TBD: detail view for {{dealer}}
```

The `{{dealer}}` var gives me all the data available in the json file... not just my specific post.

What am I missing? Thanks for the help!

Comment: well, the entirety of the response is getting assigned to `$scope.dealer`; sounds like you either need to limit what's getting returned from `files/js/dealer.json` or do something like `{{dealer.post}}`, or whatever the case may be for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are asking your web server for a file, so that is what you are getting back from the web server.  Adding an `id` parameter to the URL probably has no affect here.

You'll have to parse the contents of the file in JavaScript (e.g., in an Angular filter) to filter the data and extract only the data with the appropriate ID, or
 you'll have to change the server side:  have the web server run a script when a certain URL is received to parse the contents of the file and filter out the data with the appropriate ID.

Comment: Like "getting" a php file where I get data by the id and output it as json ? Actually the next step would be to transform the .json file into mysql data, so it would be good. Right?

Comment: Putting the data into a database, then SELECTing appropriate records by ID sounds like a much better path.